# Guard statment in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm struggling with using a guard statement in Swift

The following is designed to strop force unwrapping

```
let pages = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap{ $0.page?.html }
let titles = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap{ $0.page?.title }

guard pages != nil && titles != nil else { let error = NSError(domain: "", code: -300, userInfo: [:]);
                observer.onError(error); return }
let both = Array(zip(pages!, titles!))
```

It works, but I wanted to do something like

```
guard let pages = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap{ $0.page?.html }, titles = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap{ $0.page?.title } else {return}
```

but can't, some error about using autonomous arguments in the closure?

Why?

Comment: Yikes, don't semi-colon things like that, it becomes quite a mess. On my screen, everything after `code: -300` is clipped off.

Comment: Also, if `allpages` (which should be `allPages`, according to Swift conventions, btw), and `pages` are arrays or collections, they probably shouldn't be optional. Just use empty collections to model the "non existent" cases, rather than `nil`. It makes your call sites much nicer.

Comment: Also, array after `zip` is probably a code smell. I've very rarely seen a genuine need for an array, over the lazy ZipSequence you otherwise have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trailing closure syntax isn't allowed in `guard` statements, because of some implementation difficulties.

Here's how I would write this:

```
guard let pages = content.allpages?.pages?.lazy.compactMap({ $0.page }) else {
    observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: -300, userInfo: [:]))
    return
}

let pageHTMLs = pages.compactMap { $0.html }
let pageTitles = pages.compactMap { $0.title }
let both = Array(zip(pages, titles))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add each closure inside a pair of brackets. (Also, add `let` for the `titles`)

```
guard let pages = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap ({ $0.page?.html }), let titles = content.allpages?.pages?.compactMap ({ $0.page?.title }) else { return }
```